"URI malformed" is shown by VS Code when the path is containing Japanese
I use VS Code with an extension PHP debug.
I open a folder that the path contains Japanese (e.g. C:/tmp/日本語/www) with VS Code, and make launch.json as below:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "stopOnEntry": true
        }
    ]
}

And I make a PHP file index.php as below:
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
  echo "TEST PAGE";
?>
</body>
</html>

In IIS, I configure the site of them to http://localhost:12250/japanese/index.php.
When I start the debug mode and access there, the execution is suspended but none of lines highlighted, and VS Code says
"URI malformed".
I expect that the PHP code is highlighted and I can execute step by step.
I'm sure that the cause of this is the path containing Japanese, however, in the other Windows machines, this is not occurred. I can do the step by step execution.
Moreover, I copied the other machine's VS Code settings (%USERPROFILE%/.vscode, %APPDATA%/Code) into my machine, this is still occurred.
What is happening?? Can I repair "URI malformed" problem with Japanese path?
